# VirtualBox Cygwin Cron - Directory / Shared Folder - not found

Tags: cron, cygwin, virtualbox

physical Host = Ubuntu 18.04;
virtual Guest (VirtualBox) = Win 7 with installed Cygwin, Access to Host by Shared Folders of Virtualbox.

The above environment is working.
I use a shell script in Cygwin to save some files to the physical host. That works also.

Strange thing: when i start the same script by cron under Cygwin the mounted directories (shared folders) are not found / known by cron, only /cydrive/c is known.

Where is the issue? Virtualbox? cygwin? cron?
Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show your script? It is probably because running cron jobs does not use a login bash envrionment, so you're missing important system info, normally provided by the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

@not2qubit

crontab:
*/15 * * * * /home/sepp/my_backup_dubai

my_backup_dubai:

#!/usr/bin/csh

if (! -d /tmp/Backup) mkdir /tmp/Backup

rsync -avi --delete --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/home/sepp/list.dubai / /tmp/Backup

crontab -l >/tmp/Backup/crontab

tar czvf /cygdrive/z/Cloud/ownCloud/tmp/vmdubai.tgz /tmp/Backup

the issue is /cygdrive/z/.... this is not executed!?